# Multiplayer servers not working since 1.7.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My daughter had about 50 single player worlds on XP and now has a Windows 8 laptop. It wasn't until I read how to access her 'saves' with your simple instructions, I was able to transfer all her worlds to the Window 8.

The only problem now is none of her multi-player server addresses work since the 1.7.2. update. Is there a way to fix this or, failing that, a list of servers which will work in the new version?

Comment: We can't recommend servers for you, but we can help you with migrating the list of servers she was playing with so that, when they do update, she can go back to what she'd built there.

Answer (score 6):

The servers stopped working because you updated to the new version and they haven't. Both the server and the player need to be using the same version of Minecraft. There are two ways to fix this.

The first is to wait. Most well run servers will update as quickly as possible, though certain heavily modded servers may have to wait for the mods to update.

The second option is to run the older version of Minecraft. To do this, start the Minecraft launcher then click on New Profile in the bottom left. Change the use Version option from use latest version to use 1.6.4. You won't have the latest update but you'll be able to access multiplayer servers that haven't updated.

Answer (score 0):

the servers will most likely be updated in a couple days.
If you wont some new servers go here: [Minecraftservers.org](http://minecraftservers.org/) these are the top server all around the world. They may not be for "small" children (i dont know how old she is), but if she is around 12 she would enjoy them.
if she want to play vanilla minecraft on a server i would recommend [A Whole New world](http://www.awnw.net/) Its a very friendly server, that keeps the good old feel to minecraft.
to play on the server go to the website, and click get whitelisted and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thank you all so much, I went to minecraftservers.org  She has about five servers now and since I learnt how to transfer her single-player worlds, she now has more on her Windows 8 laptop than my old business XP in the office she played on. As far as I can tell, Minecraft has rather a cult following, my daughter can navigate like a pro!) She's so ecstatic, (she's ten by the way), I can't thank you all enough! Now I have access to my business pc, (I'm self-employed), I can now access at will for a change. Cheers Sue :-D :-D

Comment: im very glad i could help :) (if this was to an help consider marking the answar approved.

Comment: @SueRoch If this answer worked for you, the green checkmark next to the question signifies that even though this may not be the "best" answer, it worked for you - that's what's important.